# Windows Phone 8.1 How to Add Font Family

Tags: c#, xaml, fonts, windows-phone-8.1, font-family

I want to change textblock font to which in my computers font.

```
FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/scriptbl.ttf#Script MT Bold"
```

I use that code, but still font doesn't change. I can not use Blend 2013 to manage fonts. Get this error:

```
this control is disabled because the blend sdk could not be found.
```

But I use Blend and Visual Studio 2013. How can I change font?

**Edit:**

In Windows Phone 8 project, I can manage fonts, but in Windows Phone 8.1 can't do that. Does Blend is incompatible with windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Font doesn't installed on WP emulator. This code installs font on phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font family for a TextBlock in the XAML with this code:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtTest" Grid.Row="3" Text="Text" FontSize="20" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/scriptbl.ttf#Script MT Bold"/>
```

Or in the Code Behind like this:

```
txtTest.FontFamily = new FontFamily("ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/scriptbl.ttf#Script MT Bold");
```

If you're adding an external Font file to the project, make sure you set the 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy if newer'